# How can I get Laravel 5.4 last inserted id from sql server

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5

I have a table named tblMyUser. `MyUserId` is the primary key of the table. When I want to create one User using `$myUser = MyUser::create();` and when I am trying to return `$myUser->MyUserId`, it does not return the inserted id. Instead, returns a different number.

Have anyone any idea how to retrieve the inserted id?

Comment: Can you show us the migration of MyUser table and MyUser model ?

Comment: `tblMyUser` table not created by migration.Table created previously I have just create model .

Comment: Did you add this property `protected $primaryKey = 'MyUserId';`?

Comment: Yes.I have already added this. please check my model https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295738/laravel-5-4-return-wrong-last-inserted-id

Answer (score 0):

If you add user to db in controller, you have to redirect back using id from request in controller and view.

in controller -

```
return View::make('VIEW',compact('client'));
```

web.php -

```
Route::get('view', $user_id->id);
```