# Laravel 5.4 return wrong last inserted id

Tags: sql-server-2014, laravel-5.4

I am using SQL SERVER 2014 and Laravel 5.4 I habe a tble named `tblMyUser` whose primary key `MyUserId`
Now I want to insert one row in table and get Last Insered Id but this return wrong id with respect to sql server `tblMyUser` table
This is my Model MyUser.php

```
namespace App;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class MyUser extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;
        protected $table = 'tblMyUser';
        protected $primaryKey = 'MyUserId';
        protected $fillable = ['Name','DOB','CustUserId','CreatedBy','UpdatedBy'];
        public $timestamps = false;

        public static function addUser($params){
             $myUser = MyUser::create(array(
                'Name' => $params['Name'],
                'DOB' => $params['DOB'],
                'CustUserId' => $params['CustUserId'],
                'CreatedBy' => $params['CreatedBy'],
                'UpdatedBy' => $params['UpdatedBy']
            ));
            echo "<pre>";print_r($myUser->MyUserId);exit;
            // Its returning wrong Id which is not in tblMyUser
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Try `$myUserId = DB::table('tblMyUser')->insertGetId(array(
                'Name' => $params['Name'],
                'DOB' => $params['DOB'],
                'CustUserId' => $params['CustUserId'],
                'CreatedBy' => $params['CreatedBy'],
                'UpdatedBy' => $params['UpdatedBy']
            ));` just to see if it will return the the correct one !!

Answer (score 0):

**In laravel 5.4 you can get it by 2 way**

1. By using insertGetId method. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts)

   ```
   $lastID = DB::table('table_name')->insertGetId(['field_name'=>$field_vale]);
      echo $lastID;
   ```
2. By using getPdo() method.

   ```
   $lastID = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
   echo $lastID;
   ```